# Will an object in a List be garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass() {
    private List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    public MyClass() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread();
            threads.add(t);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

In my service, there is a single instance of `MyClass` that hangs around for the duration that the service runs. Via JConsole, I have observed the 10 threads get created and start doing their processing, so I know that this set up works -- to some extent.

My problem comes up when the system gets under load. When I send several thousand large objects to the service, the above threads spontaneously die. (As I observe in JConsole.) Since there's no logic defined to actually tear down the threads and/or clear the `threads` List, I'm wondering if it's possible that Java has garbage collected the actual objects from inside of the `threads` List and just left some kind of weak reference behind.

**Questions:**

- Under heavy load, is it possible that Java garbage collects the contents of the `threads` List?
- Is there another way that the contents of the `threads` List could spontaneously go away? Eg. that the threads could somehow get stopped without any explicit code ever calling some kind of cleanup logic.

(Yes, I know this is poorly designed code, but it is legacy code and I'm just trying to figure out what is currently happening before I go try and fix the implementation.)

Comment: Are you asking whether or not they are garbage collected AFTER the process is completed, or during/before the process? If the first, then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: @TheLostMind I have fixed the code. Actually it's creating these weird objects that each contain a thread that it then starts when calling the `run()` method. I tried to simplify in the code example by just having a List of thread directly, but apparently missed a spot.

Comment: Do the entries in the `List` get cleared or the threads represented by those `Thread` objects just stop? Note that a running thread cannot get GC'ed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I do not know, actually. All I have for monitoring is JConsole. The threads are there, and running, and then when I play in the heavy load, the threads disappear. My best guess at this point is that we trigger Serial Garbage Collection and they get cleaned up, but they could theoretically get interupted. (Not sure how, because they log all sorts of error messages on Interrupt.)

Comment: @MikeElofson This code is part of a service. The service runs until it is stopped. It creates a single instance of `MyClass`, which hangs around until the service gets stopped. As the threads are created in the `MyClass` constructor, they should hang around until the termination of the service, but when monitored they seem to disappear when system is under load.

Comment: Calling `run()` method does **not** create/start new thread.

Comment: Garbage collection kicks in when the reference to the object is broken. Imagine it like a pointer to an object, if you change the pointer to point to another object then there's no reference to the previous, this would be garbage collected. I've never seen the JVM randomly start collecting things, generally you will get an OutOfMemory exception because of the fact that it DOESN'T actively start removing objects still in play, even under high load.

Comment: As a general note - don't rewrite the code when you post it here - remove irrelevant parts, but don't change the logic flow...

Comment: @GermannArlington I didn't. As I noted in a previous comment I accidentally mistyped a single line and user TheLostMind was kind enough to point it out to me. As the rest of the post says, the threads correctly start and run and can be observed in JConsole, so it can be assumed that the problem is not with the *starting* of the threads.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - could you check if (actually when) the threads were interrupted in the middle of their execution?

Comment: Threads will be GCed after they finish running, not before that. So your threads must be finishing before you expect them to.

Comment: @GermannArlington - correct.. But the JVM can't just collect a Running thread as Garbage.. They must have been interrupted, then stopped (daemon-ed) then collected..

Comment: Instead of comments, someone should post these as answers.

Comment: @TheLostMind "But the JVM can't just collect a Running thread as Garbage" Is not that what I said?

Comment: @GermannArlington - I meant. Yes!. The JVM can't just...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Under heavy load, is it possible that Java garbage collects the contents of the threads List?

No and no.

No because of them being running. Running threads don't get collected.

And no because of the being stored in a list which itself is alive.

Put simply, the GC will never take away the chair you might want to sit on later.

> Is there another way that the contents of the threads List could spontaneously go away?

No. But the most important question is missing:

> **Am I doing it right?**

No. The standard way is to use `Executors`, which can provide you e.g. with a `newFixedThreadPool`. Unless you have a special requirements and good expertise, stick with it. If they don't suffice your needs, there are even [MoreExecutors](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html).

Comment: Actually the 'most important question' is covered by my last statement. I know it's done wrong, I was just trying to figure out how it could be breaking before replacing it with a thread pool.